# Using anaconda on Windows 10 Ubuntu subsystem - cygpath (?)

Tags: windows, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

1. I have installed Miniconda 3 on Windows 10 Linux - Ubuntu 16.04 subsystem.
2. I have created a new environment ...

   ```
   conda create -n myenv db
   ```
3. when I try to activate the environment, I get:

   ```
   $ source activate db
   cygpath: command not found
   shell.posix: command not found
   ```
4. what is cygpath ? why does anaconda call it ?

Comment: How did you install miniconda ?

Comment: entered bash on ubuntu,
used wget to download Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN: sh Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
that's it.
python and the libraries seems to work fine. But not

Comment: `cygpath` is a utility on cygwin (or cygwin-like) POSIX emulators for Windows to convert between UNIX and Windows file system paths. This might be a bug in conda; it detects you're on Windows but in a POSIX shell and assumes cygwin functionality.